# How can identify Mouse Click event in PreTranslateMessage?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mouseevent

I want identify all mouse click event in PreTranslateMessage, but when I use WM_LBUTTONDOWN than WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK portion never called. Please tell me how can I identify all events separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will get the mouse click events in [PreTranslateMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/49a832ee-bc34-4126-88b3-bc1d9974f6c4.aspx#cwnd__pretranslatemessage)

```
 BOOL CSampleDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
 {
    if(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
      //add ur customized code here...
      return false;
    }
    return CDHtmlDialog::preTranslateMessage(pMsg);
 }
```